# could not find or load main class but there is definitely a main class

Tags: java

I was working on my project fine on Intellij but now that i have imported it to eclipse it keeps saying "error could not find or load main class" here is my code.  there is definitely a main class.  i feel like its not running the correct program.  before, mh problem was that i couldnt select it in the package explorer because it wasnt there and now it is there but I cannot run the program because eclipse says theres no main class.

this is my main class

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class GoneFishin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create linked list of fish data called fl
        LinkedList<FishData> fl = new LinkedList<FishData>();
        //Here are a few data items
        fl.add(new FishData("American Eel ", 9, "Summer/Spring ", 25, false));
        fl.add(new FishData("Hammerhead Shark ", 0, "All Year ", 36, false));
        fl.add(new FishData("Horseshoe Crab ", 7, "All Year except May ", 60, false));
        fl.add(new FishData("Haddock ", 18, "All Year ", 0, true));
        fl.add(new FishData("Tautog ", 16, "late Spring to end of year ", 3, true));

        for (FishData element : fl) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
        System.out.print("SIZE OF LISTt: ");
        System.out.println(fl.size());

        System.out.print("SECOND ELEMENT IN LIST: ");
        System.out.println(fl.get(1));

        System.out.print("LAST ELEMENT IN LIST: ");
        System.out.println(fl.getLast());

        Iterator<FishData> itr2 = fl.iterator();

        System.out.println("PRINTING ALL ELEMENTS USING ITERATOR");
        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr2.next());
        }
        Iterator<FishData> itr = fl.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            FishData b = (FishData) itr.next();
            if (b.getWillEat()== false) {
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("FISH THAT ARE GOOD TO EAT");
        for (FishData element : fl) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try right clicking on the file with the main method in the package explorer and then go Run As -> Java application.

Comment: @VinceEmigh they say it was working in IntelliJ but after importing to Eclipse it isn't working. I'm assuming that means it isn't working in Eclipse.

Comment: This could be related to the configuration of source folders. what type of project is this? I'd need more details to know what the problem is, as there is a main method.

Comment: Not enough detail -- tell us what kind of project it is and exactly how you're attempting to run it.